# Utilizing Bootstrap .modal() JQuery method in Angular App

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-cli

I am having some functionality errors regarding Bootstrap 4 and NPM/Angular CLI regarding the .modal methods

Error: `TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

main.ts:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

app.components.ts:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

...

$('#new-product-modal').modal('hide');
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="new-product-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="new-product-modal" aria-hidden="true">
```

.angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
```

package.json:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
...
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
...
"popper.js": "^1.12.9",
```

It doesn't throw an error in Visual Studio Code or in the ng build/serve commands. But it will throw a console error and not hide the modal. All of the other functions of the modal perform as expected like data-dismiss="modal" etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your modal element is rendering after you call

```
$('#new-product-modal').modal('hide');
```

Try to use your script in a document ready function like

```
$(function(){
  $('#new-product-modal').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Doing that gives me an additional yellow warning: `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).modal is not a function` as well as the same error.

Comment: If you are still getting modal is not a function, then you might have a problem with the way you are importing bootstrap.

Comment: That's what I'm leaning towards as well. I found the import statement `import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';`, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

First step you need install `jquery` and `bootstrap` by npm command.

Second you need add `declare var $ : any;` in component (**IMPORTANT**)

And use can use `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` on onSave() method

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-model-bootstrap-close?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Declaring `$` with type `any` defeats the purpose of TypeScripts' type checking and is not a solution but a workaround. Would you consider providing an alternative solution?

Answer (score -1):

First step you need install jquery and bootstrap by npm command.

Second you need add declare var $ : any; in component (IMPORTANT)

And use can use $('#myModal').modal('hide');